# Custom Http Status Code in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and I am using Exception Classes thoughout my business logic code. One might look like this:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class ExternalDependencyException extends RuntimeException {

    public ExternalDependencyException() {
        super("External Dependency Failed");
    }
    public ExternalDependencyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

Well now there are Exception, where no predefined Http Status code is fitting, so I would like to use a status code like 460 or similar, which is still free, but the annotation `ResponseStatus` just accepts values from the enum `HttpStatus`. Is there a way to achieve an Exception class with a custom status code in the java spring boot environment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this with [@ResponseStatus](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html).

One way to solve is this issue is with [@RestControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestControllerAdvice.html).
This will allow you to customize how you return your Exception.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class WebRestControllerAdvice  {

    @ExceptionHandler(ExternalDependencyException.class)
    public String handleGitlabException(ExternalDependencyException ex, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            response.sendError(460);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to note this is since 4.3

Answer (score 3):

In general, @mdeterman answer is good, but I believe the right thing to do is setStatus to response, not sendError directly. Example:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler { 
    @ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
    public String handleException(Exception ex, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setStatus(460);
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

It seems to be possible only because of @RestControllerAdvice. @ControllerAdvice reset status code on view resolver level (for some strange reason).
Also it is important to understand: any custom status code *(not mentioned in org.apache.http.HttpStatus - RFC1945, RFC2616 , and
RFC2518)* will cause UnknownHttpStatusCodeException if client service is based on spring.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `sendError()` will use Spring default Template. You also need to use `RestControllerAdvice` instead of `ControllerAdvice`, then `setStatus()` will do the trick :)

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionService {

    @SneakyThrows
    @ExceptionHandler({CustomException.class})
    public CustomExceptionDto handle(HttpServletResponse resp, CustomException e) {
        resp.setStatus(e.getStatus().value()); //Using Spring HttpStatus
        return e.toDto();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot 2.1.8.RELEASE I did something similar but without using the HttpServletResponse:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
    public ApiErrorResponse handleTemplateEngineException(MyCustomException ex) {

        //custom ApiErrorResponse class
        return ApiErrorResponse.builder()
                .status(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
                .errorCode("NOT_ACCEPTABLE")
                .message(ex.getLocalizedMessage()).build();
    }
}
```