# How can I create user defined HttpStatus Code in Java(Spring MVC)?

Tags: spring-mvc, httpresponse, http-status-codes

I got an requirement to create a custom HTTP status Code to handle particular exception. I have googled a lot but, I didn't found any proper solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Http Status Code in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470897/custom-http-status-code-in-spring)

Comment: You can use the answer in the link below.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46471848/2445028