# How to change HTTP response status code in Postman according to my exception using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

Is it possible to change HTTP Response Status Code in Postman using Spring Boot according to my own exceptions?
I am developing API's for user account, but I want to put my own status code and its status when ever exception is thrown, like **OLD_AND_NEW_PASSWORD_CAN_NOT_BE_SAME**.
For example: I want **StatusCode: 460** and **Status: Old and New Password Can Not Be Same**

Comment: See if this quesstion helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470897/custom-http-status-code-in-spring

Comment: Yes, may be some how it will be helpful. But is there any way I can use ResponseStatus directly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes very much possible.

As mentioned earlier in comment article, you can make use of @RestControllerAdvice to define one stop shop for your exceptions

You can define your own Error Model (Basically a POJO), initialize and return as part of ResponseBody/ResponseEntity!