# Create and Return a custom Http response code in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, http-status-codes

I want to create a custom http status code and want to return it with the response for specific use cases. I can not use the status codes like `OK`, `ACCEPTED` etc.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/status/test", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Test> testStatus(@RequestBody Test test)
    throws Exception {
    // the below code is for status code 200

    HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;

    // the above declaration declares the httpStatus with code 200 but I want to create
    // a custom code like 234
    
    return new ResponseEntity<Test>(test,httpStatus);

}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470897/custom-http-status-code-in-spring).

Comment: Guess that the status is stored as an object in the a Response Entity and you could use the rawStatus Method, which just takes an int. Would not do it, because you are breaking the contract and this could have strange side effects. Probably you could use a usual status code and return your custom code inside the body? Seems to be a better approach.

Comment: @AndrewS The link you shared throw an exception and I am not looking for it

Comment: @triplem can you write it down please how to achieve this.

Comment: You could try

    return new ResponseEntity<Test>(test, null, 4711);

But, like already stated, you will definitly break the contract and it could also mean, that Spring will not return this correctly (haven't tested).
Better would be something like an own Response-Object, which contains the Test-Object as well as your custom code, like already stated by frank in one of the above answers. This will not break any contract and gives you the freedom to do anything you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could take a look at the link provided by Andrew S in the comment.

another option is encapsulate the response into a custom java bean via `@RestControllerAdvice`, this custom java bean looks like

```
public class ResultVO<T> implements Serializable{

    private int code;
    private String msg;
    private T data;
```

then you could set any custom code in it.

Answer (score -1):

You could write your custom exception like this:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class AccountNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public AccountNotFoundException(Exception ex, int id) {
        super("Account with id=" + id + " not found", ex);
    }
}
```

Then throw the exception wherever you want.
With @ResponseStatus you can give your exception it's own return code

Comment: I do not want to send an exception but a success status code